# Trying to login to Nike using requests

Tags: node.js, cookies, request, akamai, nike

I am trying to login to the Nike website using requests in nodejs (nodejs-fetch) and I have got {success:true} from Akamai but I still get 403 error after passing the returned _abck cookie from akamai. Anyone know how to fix?

Answer (score 3):

When sending an browser sensordata payload to the Bot Manager validation endpoint, {"success": true} does not indicate that the returned cookie is necessarily the final and correct one, it merely indicates that the sensordata payload was read as a valid sensordata payload. The script that generates the sensordata payload effectively runs on a loop and so it would also be necessary for your code to validate the returned cookie and if necessary, re-run the sensordata gathering portions iteratively until the returned cookie has some indicator within it that serves as a stop signal. This changes fairly often and so would be version-dependent.